# How to get css 3 column layout with floats and no margins?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I'm not very experienced with css and I encountered the following issue while trying to do a layout with fixed-width left and right columns, and a dynamic middle one.

The only way I was able to accomplish this was using margins on the middle div, to avoid the overlapping with the side columns. I imagine that there's a cleaner way of achieving this, but I haven't been able to find a solution for it yet.

See jsfiddle here with margin left and no margin on the right: http://jsfiddle.net/juansg_eng/BCJ6C/119/

```
HTML
<div class="left">With margin</div>
<div class="right">No margin</div>
<div class="middle"></div>

css
.left { float: left; width: 134px; height: 191px; background-color:#0000ff; opacity: 0.5}
.middle { height: 50px; background-color: #ff0000; margin-left: 134px}
.right { float: right; width: 183px; height: 191px; background-color:#ffff00; opacity:0.5}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flexbox` can do that. No floats or margins required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  height: 191px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.main > div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.left {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 134px;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 134px;
  flex: 0 1 134px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  opacity: 0.5
}
.middle {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000
}
.right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 183px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 183px;
  flex: 0 0 183px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari doesn't support flex

Comment: says it does check out on a safari. I know its the right thing to do and wow but added -webkit- to the code but safari doesn't. But ya great solution for other browsers and yes we never care about IE :)

Comment: I haven't added all the necessary vendor prefixes for the sake of brevity. Try this  http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EjJQQy Answer updated.

Comment: This is great. The one problem I'm finding is that, if I try to use a transform: translate(200px,0px) on one of the side columns (after clicking a button), the middle column doesn't update it's width to fill the remaining space.

Comment: Translate doesn't increase size or *actually* move the object...i just moves the element visually. You might be better off asking a **new** separate question if this is an issue

Comment: understood. Thanks @Paulie_D !

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: flex;` to middle container should do the trick.

Do check the browser support.

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 134px;
  height: 191px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  opacity: 0.5
}
.middle {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 183px;
  height: 191px;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="left">With margin</div>
<div class="right">No margin</div>
<div class="middle"></div>
```

Reference [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: When I tried this, it still flowed under the right box.

Comment: It doesn't support on lower versions. But higher versions do.

Answer (score 0):

```
.left { float: left; width: 134px; height: 191px; background-color:#0000ff; opacity: 0.5}
.middle { float:left; width: calc(100% - (134px + 183px)); height: 50px; background-color: #ff0000;}
.right { float: right; width: 183px; height: 191px; background-color:#ffff00; opacity:0.5}
```